# Set up a login form in php and the first admin login

Tags: php, session, authentication, admin

I would like to setp up a login form that will included in certain pages.

I found many tutorials that talk about it but, how can I add the "admin" account for the first time ?!
In phpmyadmin directly? I can do it but,  want it to be encoded with the md5 algorithm.
Does anybody know where can I find a ready login system with the session management and all the other stuff?

Thank you very much,
regards.

Comment: Yes. In phpmyadmin directly sounds reasonable. Otherwise, how'd you access the admin section, if no admin user exists.

Comment: Yes, but i don't want thant anybody can see the admin password without the md5 encode! How can I manage hide the admin password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHPMyAdmin insert the Admin user's password with [md5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5)

```
INSERT INTO your_user_table (username, password) VALUES ('admin', md5('secret'));
```

And in your PHP app, use the native [md5()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) function.

Note that md5() is insecure by now and you want to consider [sha1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) and salting for increased security. See

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=salt+security+php

Comment: @Gordon: "Note that md5() is insecure by and you want to consider..." *insecure by* what? My apologies for any apparent grammar-nazism, but it feels like there's a point, or at least a couple of words, being accidentally left out of the sentence... =/

Comment: @ricebowl *now*. The missing word is *now*. I was distracted because I had to get my dinner out of the oven :D Nothing wrong with being a grammar nazi :)

Comment: thanks for the understanding =) And, incidentally, +1

Answer (score 0):

you could make some kind of install script for your software which shows a form where the user enters the admin login data. This install script would add this admin and should be deleted afterwards or at least should it have minimal access rights.

But you also can add admins via phpmyadmin or other MySQL admin tools.

If you are looking for complete login solution you should take a look at some of the major PHP frameworks out there.

For example:

[Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) or
[Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)

There are many more and most of them offer session management and login solutions. But these frameworks might be a bit of a overkill if you are only looking for a simple login script.

Comment: Yes! I think it will be very userful if I could find a simple login system with session management :(

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ZendFramework and read some tutorials, like

- http://robertbasic.com/blog/login-example-with-zend_auth/

ZendFramework has excellent authentication and session management.

Comment: Yes! I think it will be very userful if I could find a simple login system with session management :( – Zakaria 16 mins ago

Comment: @Zakaria why not just try to get it working on your own and when you run into issues, come back and ask. A little bit of self initiative is encouraged.